# If the equation $|x^2+bx+c|=k$ has four real roots .....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If the equation $|x^2+bx+c|=k$ has four real roots  then which of the following option is  correct :
>
> (a) $b^2-4c >0$ and $0<k<\frac{4c-b^2}{4}$
>
> (b) $b^2-4c <0$ and $0<k<\frac{4c-b^2}{4}$
>
> (c) $b^2-4c >0$ and $0<k>\frac{4c-b^2}{4}$

Please suggest how to proceed in this problem , I am getting no clue on this.. please help thanks.

Comment: What should the graphs of $y=|x^2+bx+c|$ and $y=k$ look like if we want to have four crossings?

Comment: $|x^2 + bx + c| = k$ if and only if $x^2 + bx + c = k$ or $x^2 + bx + c = -k$. (And $k > 0$). You want the first equation to have two real roots and the second equation to have two real roots.

Comment: And if the second equation has two real roots, so does the first... @AlexZorn

Comment: no correct option, I think. (though the third one looks strange)

Comment: You understand the $| |$? We know that the modulus is always $\ge0$, so if there are any solutions we must have $k\ge0$. If that is true then we can have either $x^2+bx+c=k$ or $x^2+bx+c=-k$. Each of those quadratics can have at most 2 real solutions. The equations are only different if $k>0$, so we certainly need that. Now what is the condition for a quadratic to have 2 real roots (meaning two distinct real roots)?

Comment: @mathlove yes I agree, none of the answers seem to be correct.

Comment: @sultan Are you sure you have got all the $>,<$ signs the right way round in (a),(b),(c)?

Comment: @almagest they are all ok, especially (c). To eliminate redundant discussions (k=0, double roots etc.), the assumption of four DISTINCT roots was meant in the first place, if I'm not wrong (see my answer).  What betrays such assumption are the STRICT inequalities used in all answer alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Clearly $k$ is positive. Also, both 
$$ x^2+bx + (c-k) = 0 $$
and $$ x^2+bx + (c+k) = 0 $$
have real roots (that is, both equation [discriminants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) are positive).

(I have been assuming everywhere that there are four *distinct* real roots.)

> Note that $k>0$ and positivity of the second discriminant, $b^2-4(c+k)>0$ imply $b^2-4c>4k>0$, so $b^2-4c>0$. The third inequality comes directly from the positivity of the first discriminant, $b^2-4(c-k)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's narrow the three possibilities to one, and confirm whether it actually works.

First, note that there are three possibilities for a graph of $y=x^2+bx+c$: It passes above the the $x$-axis (and has no real roots), it just 'kisses' the $x$-axis (and has one real root), or it crosses the axis twice (two real roots). In the first two cases, the quadratic is always positive and so the absolute value has no effect. But, in the third case, the portion of the parabola below the $y$-axis is reflected into the $x>0$ half plane.

Suppose we now cross these graphs with a horizontal line $y=k$. If we have a parabola, then this line can cross the parabola at most twice; since we want four, we must have the two real roots of $x^2+bx+c=0$. If we recall the quadratic formula, this requires that $b^2-4c>0$ so that the plus/minus gives two real solutions. That eliminates option (b).

If we do have $b^2-4c>0$, then we can choose a range of $k$ such that it crosses the reflected parabola twice. By visual inspection of the reflected parabola, it should be of the form $0<k<k_{max}$. Only option (a) is of this form, with $k_{max}=\frac{4c-b^2}{4}$. To check this, note that the most negative value that $x^2+bx+c=(x+\frac{b}{2})^2+\frac{4c-b^2}{4}$ can express is $\frac{4c-b^2}{4}$ (which is negative since we require $b^2-4c>0$.) Upon taking the absolute value, this means that the reflected 'hump' of the parabola has a height of $\frac{4c-b^2}{4}$ which is indeed $k_{max}$ as in answer (a).